# How does pattern matching work in Akka.Actor receive method?

Tags: scala, akka

I am new to Scala programming and having some trouble understanding how actors works and how to use them correctly.

Looking at the source code of [an Akka actor](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Actor.scal), the following is exposed:

```
trait Actor {
  def receive: Actor.Receive // Actor.Receive = PartialFunction[Any, Unit]
}
```

My first impression of this is that Actor is a trait that exposes one abstract method, `receive` which takes no arguments and then returns a partial function. First question, is this the correct interpretation of the API?

Next, I looked at the documentation for how to implement actors. The examples look something like this:

```
class HelloActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "hello" => println("hello back at you")
    case _       => println("huh?")
  }
}
```

Clearly there is some pattern matching going on here, but I'm having trouble understanding how this works. For instance, let's say I wanted to invoke the receive method directly without using something like `send`, how would I do it?

Comment: The body of `receive` is a literal declaration of a `PartialFunction`. Why would you want to invoke this directly?

Comment: Because I'm curious about how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as others already answered, you never should directly call methods on Actors. But your question seems to be more about "how does PartialFunction work in Scala?", right?

In Scala the `PartialFunction[In, Out]` has a bit of compiler generated code for methods like `isDefinedAt`, so you can ask a partial function if it's defined for a certain argument:

```
scala> val fun: PartialFunction[Any, String] = {
     | case 42 => "yes"
     | }
fun: PartialFunction[Any,String] = <function1> 

scala> fun.isDefinedAt(12)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> fun.isDefinedAt(42)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> fun(42)
res2: String = yes

scala> fun(12)
scala.MatchError: 12 (of class java.lang.Integer)
```

```

We use the `isDefinedAt` method before we apply a message to a `receive` function, and if it's not able to handle the message we pass it into `unhandled(msg)`, which usually just logs the message to dead letters so you can figure out that your Actor didn't handle a message.

Answer (score 2):

> For instance, let's say I wanted to invoke the receive method directly without using something like send, how would I do it?

You would not.

Directly invoking the `receive` function of an actor without going through its `ActorRef` breaks the guarantees of the actor model:

1. Actors process exactly one message at a time.
2. An actor's internal state can only be mutated from the receive function.

(among others, see [What is an actor?](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.6/general/actors.html))

When you send an `ActorRef` a message, you aren't directly talking to the actor.  Hidden behind the `ActorRef` are any number of implementation details—you could be sending a message to a router or a remote actor or a dead actor (or all three!).  Isolating an actor's details behind this reference allows the guarantees that are the entire point of the actor model.

Comment: I understand the actor model. I'm more interested in how partial functions work and would like to understand how `receive` is called/used internally.